# Redirect using history in actioncreator and react-router v.4

Tags: react-router-v4

I'm trying to navigate programmatically in action creator after calling an API and receiving a response.
What I did:
I created a file **utils/History.js** with this code:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

and then used it in action creator:

```
import History from '../../utils/History';
//some code
History.replace('/sign-in');
```

Of course, I let relevant component know about this routing. If I use `<NavLink to='/sign-in'>`, it works. But if I want to render this component on History.replace('/sign-in') or History.push('/sign-in'), I can see just 'localhost:8080/sign-in' in address bar, but relevant component doesn't appear.
Please help me to figure out.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this scenario?

Comment: Hi! Solved there: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4895

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create a `history.js` file:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createHistory();
```

And then, in your `action.js` (or `actions/index.js`, whatever you prefer):

```
import history from './history';
history.push('/your_route');
```